# Get the final key of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a standard associative array in PHP. what's the simplest way to get the last key in that array?

example:

```
$foo = array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', 'key3' => 'val3');
```

and i would like to get 'key3';

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fastest method would be this:

```
end($foo);
$last = key($foo);
```

Tesserex's method is unnecessarily resource hungry when you don't need all keys.

Comment: ;-) I even looked for some nice way to save the internal pointer so you could go back afterwards, but couldn't find any nice way to do it...

Comment: @Emil Good point, I've also just looked and I don't think there's a way to save the pointer state (no function exposes `zend_hash_get_pointer` and `zend_hash_set_pointer`). Would be a nice addition.

Comment: @Justin Johnson It rewinds the pointer, doesn't put it where it were.

Comment: Oh right.  I believe the only way to do that is to duplicate the array, and work on the duplicate .... which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 8):

```
$keys = array_keys($foo);
$last = end($keys);
```

you need to pass an actual variable to `end`, you can't put another function inside there.

Answer (score 1):

The following is **not** the **simplest**, but it <del>will</del> may be much happier to deal with large (in terms of number of elements; though will probably<sup>†</sup> be better for most uses) arrays than the other answers.

```
$last_key = key(array_slice($subject, -1, 1, true));
```

<sup><sup>†</sup> educated guess, may not be true for *all cases*</sup>

Comment: I tend to disagree. I tried all three solutions on an array with 10000 integer values and my solution was about 20 times faster than yours. Results in seconds, measure by microtime(): typical time for yours: 0.00013. Typical time for mine: 0.0000069. Typical time for Tesserex: 0.003.

Comment: On a small array (hundred integer values): Yours: 0.000015. Mine: 0.000005. Tesserex: 0.00003

Comment: I'm not going to starting giving benchmark results suffice to say, I tend to disagree. Either way, the OP was after the **simplest** which mine certainly is not. :-)

Comment: @Emil Unless you're finding the end of 100's of huge array, micro-benchmarking is a useless discussion.